# How to repeat certain rows of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': list('AAABBC'),
    'prop1': list('xyzuuy'),
    'prop2': list('mnbnbb')
})

  key prop1 prop2
0   A     x     m
1   A     y     n
2   A     z     b
3   B     u     n
4   B     u     b
5   C     y     b
```

and a dictionary like this (user input):

```
d = {
    'A': 2,
    'B': 1,
    'C': 3,
}
```

The keys of `d` refer to entries in column `key` in `df1`, the values indicate how often the rows of `df1` that belong to the respective keys should be present: `1` means that nothing has to be done, `2` means all lines should be copied once, `3` they should be copied twice.

For the example above, the expected output looks as follows:

```
   key prop1 prop2
0    A     x     m
1    A     y     n
2    A     z     b
3    B     u     n
4    B     u     b
5    C     y     b
6    A     x     m  # <-- copied, copy 1
7    A     y     n  # <-- copied, copy 1
8    A     z     b  # <-- copied, copy 1
9    C     y     b  # <-- copied, copy 1
10   C     y     b  # <-- copied, copy 2
```

So, the rows that belong to `A` have been copied once and added to `df1`, nothing had to be done about the rows the belong to `B` and the rows that belong to `C` have been copied twice and were also added to `df1`.

I currently implement this as follows:

```
dfs_to_add = []
for el, val in d.items():
    if val > 1:
        _temp_df = pd.concat(
            [df1[df1['key'] == el]] * (val-1)
        )
        dfs_to_add.append(_temp_df)

df_to_add = pd.concat(dfs_to_add)
df_final = pd.concat([df1, df_to_add]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

which gives me the desired output.

The code is rather ugly; does anyone see a more straightforward option to get to the same output?

The order is important, so in case of `A`, I would need

```
0   A     x     m
1   A     y     n
2   A     z     b
0   A     x     m
1   A     y     n
2   A     z     b
```

and not

```
0   A     x     m
0   A     x     m
1   A     y     n
1   A     y     n
2   A     z     b
2   A     z     b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can sue `concat` + `groupby`

```
df=pd.concat([ pd.concat([y]*d.get(x)) for x , y in df1.groupby('key')])
  key prop1 prop2
0   A     x     m
1   A     y     n
2   A     z     b
0   A     x     m
1   A     y     n
2   A     z     b
3   B     u     n
4   B     u     b
5   C     y     b
5   C     y     b
5   C     y     b
```

Answer (score 2):

One way using `Index.repeat` with `loc[]` and `series.map`:

```
m = df1.set_index('key',append=True)
out = m.loc[m.index.repeat(df1['key'].map(d))].reset_index('key')
```

---

```
print(out)
  key prop1 prop2
0   A     x     m
0   A     x     m
1   A     y     n
1   A     y     n
2   A     z     b
2   A     z     b
3   B     u     n
4   B     u     b
5   C     y     b
5   C     y     b
5   C     y     b
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `repeat`:

```
df1.loc[df1.index.repeat(df1['key'].map(d))]
```

Output:

```
  key prop1 prop2
0   A     x     m
0   A     x     m
1   A     y     n
1   A     y     n
2   A     z     b
2   A     z     b
3   B     u     n
4   B     u     b
5   C     y     b
5   C     y     b
5   C     y     b
```

Comment: In case there are entries in `df` which are not contained in `d` one can do: `df1['key'].map(d).fillna(1).astype(int)`.

Comment: Sorry for deselecting again; just realized that the order is not correct. In case of `A` the index should be `0 1 2 0 1 2` and not `0 0 1 1 2 2`. Any ideas? (updated my question as that was not very well stated).

Comment: If order is crucial, best is to do `concat` as other answers.

Answer (score 2):

If order is not important, use another solutions.

If order is important get indices of repeated values, repeat by `loc` and add to original:

```
idx = [x for k, v in d.items() for x in df1.index[df1['key'] == k].repeat(v-1)]

df = df1.append(df1.loc[idx], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   key prop1 prop2
0    A     x     m
1    A     y     n
2    A     z     b
3    B     u     n
4    B     u     b
5    C     y     b
6    A     x     m
7    A     y     n
8    A     z     b
9    C     y     b
10   C     y     b
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
df = df1.merge(
    pd.Series(np.repeat(list(d.keys()), list(d.values())), name='key'), on='key')
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

   key prop1 prop2
0    A     x     m
1    A     x     m
2    A     y     n
3    A     y     n
4    A     z     b
5    A     z     b
6    B     u     n
7    B     u     b
8    C     y     b
9    C     y     b
10   C     y     b
```